# Absolute path being treated as relative

Tags: java, windows-10, netbeans-8

I've run into a bit of code where an absolute path is being treated as relative.
So far I've been unable to reproduce this in other projects.

I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2 with JDK 8u51 on Windows 10.

Here's the bit of code:

```
public void setImagePath(String path) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    System.out.printf("path:     %s\n", path);
    System.out.printf("resolved: %s\n", file.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.printf("test:     %s\n", new java.io.File("C:/users/rando/desktop/test.jpg").getAbsolutePath());
    img = ImageIO.read(file);
    reloadImage();
}
```

And here's the output:

```
path:     ‪C:\users\rando\desktop\test.jpg
resolved: C:\Users\rando\Dropbox\Other\NetBeans Projects\Applications\test\‪C:\users\rando\desktop\test.jpg
test:     C:\users\rando\desktop\test.jpg
```

Notice that halfway through the "resolved" line, it begins the absolute path with C:...

Can anyone shed any light on this?

My only guess is that this is a Windows 10 issue.

EDIT:

So, in a way, it is a Windows 10 issue. On Windows 7 I would always obtain the full path to a particular file by going to its properties and copying the object name from the security tab. In Windows 10 it apparently now has an additional control character.

Comment: Did you try passing a `path` with forward slashes instead of backslashes, i.e. `"C:/users/rando/desktop/test.jpg"`?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. A single `\ ` causes a compiler error if used in a String literal and if I enter it using the console, I get the correct output.

Comment: Try printing the length of `path`.  I have the feeling it may have a byte order mark or other control characters in it.

Comment: @VGR you're onto somethhing... : `path:         ‪C:\users\rando\desktop\test.jpg
path len:     32
resolved:     C:\Users\rando\Dropbox\Other\NetBeans Projects\Applications\test\‪C:\users\rando\desktop\test.jpg
resolved len: 100
test:         C:\users\rando\desktop\test.jpg
test len:     31`

Comment: Notepad and some other editors place a byte order mark at the start of UTF-16-encoded text files (sometimes), to indicate the endianness of the UTF-16 encoding.  What does `System.out.printf("%04x%n", path.codePointAt(0));` print?

Comment: @VGR that prints `202a`

Comment: Seems to be the [left-to-right indicator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202A/index.htm).

Comment: Looks like you have a Unicode LRE control code in your text.  Easiest fix is `path = path.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");`.

Comment: @VGR I guess you should write that in an answer.

Comment: Interesting! I'm not sure how it got there, I pasted the path from the security tab in the file properties window for that particular file. In the past I always found that nonprintable characters still have to have the caret move twice to get past the nonprintable character (i.e. you press left/right arrow and the caret stays still), but in this case, when navigating over the String literal in Netbeans, it doesn't behave that way.

Comment: I did, however, have to do an extra backspace to get rid of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a Unicode [LRE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/) control code in your path string.  The easiest fix is

```
path = path.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
```

which will remove all control characters.

Comment: The control character was in a String literal, so all I had to do was backspace it out. However, this seems like something Netbeans should have a warning for (nonprintable characters in String literals).

Comment: @TravisBruce Why? I wouldn't want it.

Comment: @EJP Because I would imagine most people would very rarely want to have nonprintable characters in their String literals (save for carriage returns and newlines), and bugs resulting from them can be pretty confusing to track down.